# jquery.find() unrecognized regex expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Im trying to find a div with a name and a maximum of 2 digits via jquery.find();  Example: "#progressText1", "#progressText2", ..."#progressText12", etc

This is my code (where closeForm is the form that it has the div elements):

```
var closeDiv= closeForm.find("#progressText[/^\d{1,2}$/;]");
```

And im getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #progressText[/^d{1,2}$/;]
```

Can someone help me to make it work?

Comment: You can't use regular expressions in selectors. Do you just want to get all elements whose IDs start with `progressText`?

Comment: yes, silver answer solves it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the jquery selector "starts with"

```
// assumes closeForm is a jQuery object already formed.

var closeDiv = closeForm.find('div[id^="progressText"]');
```

Comment: Great stuff! don't forget to select it as the answer :)